# Time complexity - diagram

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, diagram

I'm trying to make a diagram created from data where I've measured time execution for a given number of elements in the array.

I've made a table in Excel and created a diagram but it doesn't suit as the time complexity of my program is O(logn) and diagram came out like linear.

Time execution for given number of element is quite close-up as I was refreshing a browser, the time execution was different each, there were differences by 40-80ms let's say.

What have I done wrong that the diagram came out not similar to its time complexity?

```
<script>

    //generate array
    var size = 10000000; // number of elements
    var max = 10000; // max value in the array
    var tab = [];
    
    for(k=0; k<size; k++)
    {
        los = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
        tab[k] = los;
    }
    tab.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;}); // 
    //------------------------------------------------
    
    
    function count(tab, w, n)
    {
        
        idMin = first(tab, 0, n-1, w, n);    
        
        
        if (idMin == -1){return idMin};         
        
    
        idMax = last(tab, idMin, n-1, w, n); 
        amount = idMax-idMin+1;                  
        
        return amount;                           
    }
    
    function first(tab, l, p, w, n) 
    {
        if(l <= p) 
        {
            mid = Math.floor((l+p)/2); 
            
            if((mid == 0 || w  > tab[mid-1])&&(tab[mid] == w)) 
            {
                return mid; 
            }
            else if(w > tab[mid])
            {
                return first(tab, (mid+1), p, w, n);
            }
            else
            {
                return first(tab, l, (mid-1), w, n);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    function last(tab, l, p, w, n)
    {
        if(l <= p)
        {
            mid2 = Math.floor((l+p)/2);
                
            if((mid2 == n-1 || w < tab[mid2+1]) && (tab[mid2] == w))
            {
                return mid2; 
            }
            else if(w < tab[mid2])
            {
                return last(tab, l, (mid2-1), w, n);
            }
            else
            {
                return last(tab, (mid2+1), p, w, n);
            }
        }   
    }
    

    w = 49; //searching value
    n = tab.length; 
    
    console.time("test");
    how_many = count(tab, w, n); 
    console.timeEnd("test");
    
    if(how_many == -1)
    {
        document.write("The value "+w+" showed 0 times<br/>");
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("The value "+w+" showed "+how_many+" times<br/>");
    }

    
    
</script>
```

Diagram in Excel
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the time complexity of `tab.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});` is `O(n logn)` instead of `O(logn)` .

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763205/what-is-array-prototype-sort-time-complexity) says, browsers like Chrome now use Timsort Algorithm, whose time complexity has a lower bound of O(n) and an upper bound of O(n logn).

According to the data you give here, the maximum number of elements is 20 times the minimum. Since log(20) is just nearly 1.3, close to 1, so the line in the graph seems linear.

Comment: So theoretically I should make more test to see better result? And the other thing, tab.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;}); is nothing to do with that because I'm counting time execution(time complexity) of count() functions which includes first(), last(). The rest of program is only the addition.

Comment: I didn't read through all the code carefully, that's my fault. Sorry for that.

Comment: So again, what should I change to see the diagram more like a logarithm function?