# how does Object sort it keys of number that added to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting, object

as I'm coding with object it's occur to me that I could sort this array of number using object instead of sort prototype.since it much faster to sort using by just putting every number in an array into that object then convert it back to array would result in way faster sorting of O(2n) complexity in any case and O(n) in sorted array.

the things that confuse me is how object sort their number when we insert them?

so I try create an array unsorted and repeating number

```
//for random value test array
let arr = [];
const arrlen = 100000;
for(let i = 0 ; i < arrlen ; i++){
  arr.push( Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1))
}
```

then try to sort using object

```
//using object sorting
const performance = window.performance;  
//start
const t0 = performance.now();
let sorted = true;
let prev = arr[0]
let obj = {}  
arr.forEach((val,index)=>{
    if(index > 0 && sorted){
        if(prev > val){
            sorted = false;
        }
        prev = val
    }
    (obj.hasOwnProperty(val))? obj[val] += 1 : obj[val] = 1
}) 
let sortobj = []
if(!sorted){
  for(key in obj){
    let len = obj[key]
    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
      sortobj.push(+key)
    }
  }
}
```

then I sort using sort prototype also as refered to this [What is Array.prototype.sort() time complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763205/what-is-array-prototype-sort-time-complexity) I know firefox use merge sort and timsort for chrome.

```
// using sort prototype
const tm0 = performance.now();
console.log(arr.sort((a,b)=>  a - b))
const tm1 = performance.now();
console.log("sort by sort prototype took " + (tm1 - tm0).toFixed(4) + " milliseconds.")
```

Comment: You cannot sort an object. Objects do not retain a reliable insertion order. In order to sort, sort your array like this: **Alphabetical sort:** `array.sort()` or `['a','x','c'].sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : -1)` for more flexibility // **Numerical sort:** `array.sort((a,b) => a - b)`

Comment: I agree on alphabetical order it's is not sorted but numerical one object is always sorted.

Comment: This works like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort - but is unbounded by taking advantage of the internal sorting of integer keys on objects. These do themselves require either a large allocation or a different sorting algorithm for hash map keys. So no, it is not `O(n)`, as you ignore the complexity of object enumeration and/or property access.

Comment: @Bergi hi I just noticed on my sorting really similar to this counting sort and prob really is. the things that still confused me is how is this "object enumeration and/or property access" work exactly  ?