# Find Smallest Number from javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a form where the user enters their city, this then returns for all the cities where my client is based in a 30 mile radius. I am now trying to find the closest city out of these and return just one result with both City Name and Distance (in metres).

I have a for loop which processes my results:

```
for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
  var results = response.rows[i].elements;
  //console.log(response);
  for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

    // If distance is less than 30 miles (48280 metres)
    if(results[j].distance.value < 48280) {
      var closestCitiesDist = results[j].distance.value
      var closestCitiesName = origins[i]

      var closestCities = {"cityName" : closestCitiesName, "cityDistance" : closestCitiesDist}
      console.log(closestCities);

    }

  }
}
```

This now returns an array for each result, containing cityName and cityDistance variable. Out of each of these arrays, I would like to find the single closest city (the array with the smallest cityDistance), and be able to output "City xx is the closest (xxx metres away)"

Comment: Sounds like a job for `.sort()`, with a sorting function passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which has [a time complexity of `O(n log n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763205/what-is-array-prototype-sort-time-complexity) or instead you could do a single backwards pass of [bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) in `O(n)`, to bring the smallest city to the front of the array.

```js
const object = [
  { cityName: 'Vancouver', cityDistance: 3 },
  { cityName: 'Paris', cityDistance: 4 },
  { cityName: 'London', cityDistance: 1 },
];

for (let i = object.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  if (object[i].cityDistance < object[i - 1].cityDistance) {
    temp = object[i - 1];
    object[i - 1] = object[i];
    object[i] = temp;
  }
}

console.log(
  `City ${object[0].cityName} is the closest (${object[0].cityDistance} metres away)`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Array.prototype.sort()` on an array of objects, and sort it as you wish

**Reference Material**: [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Here element at the `0` index will have the smalles `value` property

```js
const object = [{ name: 'test', value: 3}, { name: 'test2', value: 1}];

const sorted = object.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
console.log(sorted);
```