# Is sort first then filtering faster? Or vice versa? Most optimal?

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

I have an array of 2000+ authors. I need to sort by the name that has the most post, but also filter out any names that don't have any posts.

In my head im thinking filtering first, then sorting would be faster. But upon testing using Performance.now, they seem to be the same? (Tested on a small list (10-20 authors).

```
items.filter((item) => item.author.posts.total)
          .sort(function (a, b) {
            return (
              b.author.posts.total -
              a.author.posts.total
            );
          })

OR

items.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (
              b.author.posts.total -
              a.author.posts.total
            );
          })
.filter((item) => item.author.posts.total)
```

Comment: Does your filtering benefit from having them in any particular order? If not, then it's usually faster to sort less data.

Comment: Test on 100000, 10-20 is almost nothing

Comment: You got the correct result - with small arrays it would not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On small samples of data, it doesn't change anything but on large ones, it is better to filter first and then sort because the best sorting algorithms are `O(n log n)` so the less data you have, the faster it is, and filtering shrinks the size of the sample, so filtering first is faster.

Hope it helped you !

Comment: _"js uses quicksort"_... [not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763205/283366)

Comment: Just an info: *"js uses quicksort"*... well, there's JS the **language** and JS the **implementation**, and you cannot guarantee that.

Answer (score 1):

> Tested on a small list (10-20 authors).

Performance testing means absolutely nothing unless the data in question is large enough to take a nontrivial amount of CPU to process. [Even then, they're often unreliable.](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html).

That said, assuming you have a large amount of items in the array, and the array isn't sorted in any way already, it should be faster to remove the undesirable items from the array first with `.filter` than to include sort them unnecessarily, then remove them afterwards. Filtering has `O(n)` computational complexity; sorting has `O(n log n)` complexity (if the data starts out completely unsorted).